# Python beautifulSoup WebScrape Span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

want the price for the laptops, dont need the product name
running into problems as the span is not detected.
http> https://www.atea.no/eshop/products/pc-server/baerbare-pcer/baerbare-pcer-1/

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.atea.no/eshop/products/pc-server/baerbare-pcer/baerbare-pcer-1/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
price = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"nsv-product-price ns-font-title_5"})
```

picture>

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. I don't get what you want to achieve. Please consider to take a look [example]

Comment: For future reference, you may want to try and use tickmarks to make your code cleaner so it is easier for us to read, for example ``` code ```

Answer (score 1):

The data is embedded within the page inside `<script>` tag. You can use `re`/`json` module to extract it.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = 'https://www.atea.no/eshop/products/pc-server/baerbare-pcer/baerbare-pcer-1/'

html_data = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\.netset\.model\.productListDataModel = (.*);', html_data)[1])

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

all_data = []
for p in data['response']['productlistrows']['productrows']:
    all_data.append({'Label': p['descriptiondata']['label'], 'Price': p['pricedata']['priceOnly']})


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                Label    Price
0   Dell Latitude 5500 - 15.6" - Core i5 8265U - 8...   7271.0
1   Dell Latitude 5400 - 14" - Core i5 8265U - 8 G...   7514.0
2   HP EliteBook 840 G6 - 14" - Core i7 8565U - 16...  14397.0
3   Apple MacBook Air with Retina display - 13.3" ...  13430.0
4   Apple MacBook Air with Retina display - 13.3" ...  13350.0
5   Apple MacBook Air with Retina display - 13.3" ...  13300.0
6   HP EliteBook x360 1030 G4 - 13.3" - Core i5 82...  16771.0
7   HP EliteBook x360 1030 G4 - 13.3" - Core i7 85...  21308.0
8   HP ZBook 15v G5 Mobile Workstation - 15.6" - C...  15865.0
9   Dell Latitude 5400 - 14" - Core i5 8250U - 8 G...   8833.0
10  Dell XPS 15 7590 - 15.6" - Core i9 9980HK - 32...  24523.0
11  Dell XPS 13 7390 - 13.3" - Core i7 10510U - 16...  14969.0
12  HP EliteBook x360 830 G6 / i5-8265U / 8GB / SS...  15591.0
13  HP EliteBook 830 G6 - 13.3" - Core i5 8265U - ...  12875.0
14  Dell Latitude 5500 - 15.6" - Core i7 8665U - 1...  11191.0
15  Dell Latitude 5400 - 14" - Core i5 8365U - 16 ...   9725.0
16  Dell Latitude 7400 2-in-1 - 14" - Core i5 8265...  15717.0
17  Dell Latitude 7400 2-in-1 - 14" - Core i7 8665...  19033.0
18  HP Elite Dragonfly - 13.3" - Core i7 8565U - 1...  20977.0
19  HP EliteBook x360 1040 G6 - 14" - Core i7 8565...  20678.0
```

Comment: that is ace, Andrej, extraordinary efficient solution.